# Как не обновлять переменную в While?

Tags: python, aiogram, циклы

Модуль Aiogram как-бы зацикливает всю весь код.
Условно:

```
test_bool = False
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    test_bool = True
    us_id = message.from_user.id
    await message.reply("test", reply_markup=nav.main)
    print(us_id)
@dp.message_handler()
async def send_pr(message: types.Message):
    if test_bool == True:
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Test")
```

Так вот `test_bool` всегда будет равен False, ведь Aiogram выполняет весь код заново.
Как же мне сделать все это нормально? Чтобы код работал так, как нужно (Т.е. после /start test_bool была True)
Может быть вопрос тупой, но до меня не доходит

Пробовал сделать через отдельный файл - не помогло (В файле оно вообще всегда статичное будет)
Через функцию так же

Answer (score 1):

`aiogram` не выполняет весь код заного, просто для изменения глобальной переменной вы должны прописать `global variable`

```py
variable = 0


def function():
    global variable
    variable = 1
```

Но в вашем случае, использование подобных глобальных переменных - крайне плохое решение, ведь вы пользуетесь асинхронностью и состояние гонки привет)

Вероятно вы захотите использовать базу-данных, такую как `SQLite`, `MySQL` или `PostgreSQL` для подобной цели.